# WritableStream constructor defines underlying sink as optional, what could be possible use of a stream with no sink?

Tags: javascript

I was going through [`WritableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream/WritableStream) documentation on MDN and found that a `WritableStream` can be created even without an underlying sink. What could be possible use case for this?

If my understanding is correct, without a sink, the stream data which such writable stream gulps would be obliviated to nothing.

Why would spec define such a thing? It doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense given that all of the sink's methods are optional, including `write`. But that just begs the question: What's the purpose of a sink with no `write` method?

I think it serves largely the same purpose as `/dev/null`: You can use a stream with no sink (or a sink with no `write` method) to send the data nowhere (probably in one of multiple branches of code, where other branches create writable streams that actually send the data somewhere).

It was added (back) by [this commit](https://github.com/whatwg/streams/pull/1035/commits/dbf913f0483deff9f0915fcb89b484c8787c5b84). The comment on that commit is:

> Make first arguments optional again

The "again" suggests there was some back-and-forth in the discussions around it, but I can't find those discussions.

For a primary source answer, you could open an issue asking the question.

Comment: It seems they were made non-optional in [this commit](https://github.com/whatwg/streams/commit/b046c93827f0517aa021a7e0c3f86a827ed8e5b6), but without surrounding discussion